# Core Data Problems

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I am trying to save two arrays `titles` and `bodys`in Core Data. I am having trouble finding my error in my code. I think the code below is pretty self-explanatory. I am also unable to tell if my problem is that the data is not saving properly, and there, therefore, there is nothing to load next time. Or it had saved properly and the loading never works.

Lastly, the function loadAPIData is called everytime the app is open.

My first thought for the error is that it is a threading issue

```
func loadCoreData() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Saved")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]{
            if let title = result.value(forKey: "title") as? String {
                titles.append(title)
            } else if let body = result.value(forKey: "body") as? String {
                bodys.append(body)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("failed")
    }
}

func saveCoreData() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext


    let fetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Saved")
    let request = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetch)
    do {
        _ = try context.execute(request)
    } catch {
        print("we could not delete")
    }
    //delete first ^^^


    //save everything
    let newValue = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Saved", into: context)
    for a in 0..<bodys.count {
        newValue.setValue(titles[a], forKey: "title")
        newValue.setValue(bodys[a], forKey: "body")
        do {
            try context.save()
        }
        catch {
            print("Did not save")
        }
    }
}
```

another method that might be useful:

```
var titles: [String] = []
var bodys: [String] = []


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

        titles.remove(at: indexPath.item)
        bodys.remove(at: indexPath.item)
        table.reloadData()
        saveCoreData()

    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    loadCoreData()
    if (bodys.count == 0) {
        loadAPIData()
        saveCoreData()
    }

    //some ommited because irrelevant
}
```

[image: Scheme for Core Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going about this all wrong, use the Saved entity as an class in your code as well and skip this delete all/insert all logic you have.

Replace titles and body arrays with

```
var savedItems: [Saved]()
```

and replace the do {} in loadCoreData() with

```
do {
    savedItems() = try context.fetch(request)
}
```

delete in the tableView(... commit...) method by simply doing

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let saved = savedItems[indexPath.row]
context.delete(saved)
```

And in the saveCoreData() function, remove the fetch logic and the delete logic and simply do a save of your context.

```
do {
    try context.save()
} catch {
    print("Did not save")
}
```

I haven't pin-pointed what is wrong with your code but this should make the code simpler and make it easier to find any bugs in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge changes after your batch delete request..

This is how i do it

```
let moc = context

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Members")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    moc.perform {



        // create deletion request.
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request)
        deleteRequest.resultType = .resultTypeObjectIDs

        do {

            let resultBox = try moc.execute(deleteRequest) as! NSBatchDeleteResult
            let objectIdArray = resultBox.result as? [NSManagedObjectID]
            let changes = [NSDeletedObjectsKey : objectIdArray]
            NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes, into: [moc])

            do {
                try context.save()
            }
            catch {

            }

            // save after deletion

            for objectToSave in self.objectArray {
                let object = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "YourEntity", into: context)

                objectToSave.setValue(member.duration, forKey: "duration")

                do {
                    try context.save()
                }
                catch {

                }

            }

            do {
                let results = try context.fetch(request)
                print(results.count)
            }

            catch {
                print("Error")
            }

        }
        catch {
            print("error encountered")
            abort()
        }
    }
```

[Source: Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/CoreData_Batch_Guide/BatchDeletes/BatchDeletes.html)